# How do we do System.config (angular/systemjs?) now? ("System.config is not a function")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, systemjs

I've inherited an old C# MVC/TypeScript/Angular project with a remit to make it go. Part of the process has involved upgrades of several node packages, and nuget packages. I'm thus occasionally getting stuck with a project that is written in a style I've never used, written in a style that might be too old for how Angular et al now work, and I'm not even sure what the end result is supposed to look like or do. But I appreciate a challenge.

As part of the upgrades systemjs went from v0.2 ish to 2.1 ish. Also Angular stuff was v2.ish and is now v7.ish, and some packages changed name eg angular2-in-memory-web-api -> angular-in-memory-web-api

Thankfully, it's pretty barebones as a project, so hopefully the problems are fairly elementary at this stage.

I have a systemjs.config.ts (that is being compiled successfully to .js) that looks like this:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: '/Scripts/Discussion',
            shared: '/Scripts/shared',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            shared: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

And the page that contains my app looks like this HTML (when MVC has finished outputting it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <base href="/123/discussion/">
    <title>_BoardLayout</title>

<script src="/Scripts/Libraries/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Libraries/jquery.signalr-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/polyfills/Intl.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/TinyMce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Discussion/systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        window["localeStrings"] = {
            strings: {
            }
        };
        window["appConfig"] = { apiUrl: "/api/" };
        window["sessionConfig"] = { token: '123', role: 'moderator', userId: 1 };
        System.import('app').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>

    <link href="/Content/less/discussion.less" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>

<discussion-app></discussion-app>

</body>
</html>
```

The `System.import` works fine; I can see it in the autocomplete in the console, but `System.config` is absent. What are we doing as a replacement these days?

NB: I caught this: [System.config is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786380/system-config-is-not-defined) that seems to imply that System.config is gone, and instead it should be `<script`>ed as a block of json but I didn't understand what I needed to do with it in my MVC/typescripted situation, in particular a clean way to present it on page without Razor interpreting the multiple `@angular` within the script

Lastly, I'm not averse to binning systemjs entirely if I should be loading my modules another way these days, in which case some pointers on how to reconfigure the project would be welcome

Comment: I would highly recommend if at all possible dropping system.js and instead using the Angular CLI.